# Show toast/notification in any user profile from a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, toast, android-toast

I'm learning about Android app development for multi-profile scenarios and created a simple service that displays a toast message every few seconds. The service calls `startForeground`.

As expected, the toast messages are displayed and a notification (required by `startForeground`) is showing in the notification bar.

Update: The toast is shown using a Handler, following the same approach as was recommended in the answers:

```
Handler handler =new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
   Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

});

HOWEVER, when logging onto another user profile:

- the notification is no longer present in the notification bar, and
- the toasts no longer appear.

I know that the service is still running as it continues to output log messages (`adb logcat`), and there are no error messages that would indicate this call to display the toast is failing:

I tried programmatically stopping and re-starting the service after logging onto the new user profile, but without luck. If the application is manually re-started in the new user profile, the toasts and notification *do* appear.

This is not a system application, so a solution requires permissions granted to system apps would not be acceptable.

Is it possible for a service to display toast messages from a service, regardless of the current user profile?

Comment: You should use __Handler__ or __Broadcast Receiver__ to update your UI.

Comment: Thanks @Piyush Gupta. I *am* using Handler (updated the question to reflect that.) That is how I was able to display the toasts from the first user profile. It works fine, but when switching to the second profile, the toasts no longer appear.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show Toast from Service. Only UI thread can do UI related things and Toast is UI too. See [Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) for details.

You can try this approach:

Add to your service:

```
protected Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

and then you need to post the `Runnable` to show Toast:

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I am doing it exactly that way, and updated the question to clarify that. The problem is that while this works (toasts are displayed) in the user profile that launched the app, the toasts stop appearing when switching to another profile. Can this code be modified to make the toasts appear across profiles, or is there a better way?